# Validation is changing page URL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an HTML region in the page, where I have few fields and button. Button is set to `Submit page` action.

On the same page I have Validation process, with `Function returning Error text` type.
This is the `Validation expression 1`:

```
if :P5_CELL_LEFT + :P5_CELL_RIGHT = 10 then
   return 'Stop it!';
else
   return null;
end if;
```

`Validation expression 2` is empty. Now when there is no error and function doesn't return null, then the page URL stays intact (https://domain.com/f?p=333:5:0::NO:::). However, when validation is not passing, then I see the error message on top of page, but the current page url is changing to `https://domain.com/wwv_flow.accept`. How to prevent current page URL from changing, even if validation is not passed?

Comment: This is just how it works. What problem is being caused by the url changing?

Comment: The problem is that in this state if user refreshes the page, then he gets warning dialog about re-submitting form data. For my task and the users of app this is not acceptable.

Comment: Good question. I don't know the answer to be honest. It's possible that if you're using Apex then it will just have to "be acceptable". However, I've starred this and hopefully someone will be able to offer another idea.

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you're really trying to accomplish? Once you submit the page wwv_flow.accept is the standard APEX behavior.  In addition to the APEX validation, you could use some JS for your validation and stop page submission. That would maintain the URL intact.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on JS, perhaps give some directions?